# Sum of multiplication of all combination of m element from an array of n elements

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have an array `{1, 2, 5, 4}` and `m = 3`.
I need to find:

```
1*2*5 + 1*2*4 + 1*5*4 + 2*5*4
```

i.e Sum of multiplication of all combination of m element from an array of n elements.

One of the solution possible is to find all combination and then solving it but that would be `O(nCm)` solution. Is there any better algorithm?

Comment: How would you imagine solving it other way than that?

Comment: do you want us to define algorithm for this? first try it yourself.

Comment: If you want to know if there's a formula for this instead of finding all the combinations, try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: O(2^n)? this formula is not correct!

Comment: Multiplication is commutative and associative. Just count the factors.

Comment: @PhamTrung why not? Big-oh notation represents an upper bound.

Comment: @JanDvorak uhm yes, but tighter bound is better :)

Comment: There's an alternative O(m n)-time algorithm that uses [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) (you're evaluating the mth elementary symmetric polynomial).

Answer (score 5):

This problem is equivalent to calculation of Mth coefficient of polynom with given roots ([Vieta's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)). Adapted algorithm in Delphi (O(N) memory and O(N^2) time):

```
 function CalcMultiComb(const A: array of Integer; const M: Integer): Integer;
  var
    i, k, N: Integer;
    Coeff: TArray<Integer>;
  begin
    N := Length(A);
    if (N = 0) or (M > N) then
      Exit;
    SetLength(Coeff, N + 1);

    Coeff[0] := -A[0];
    Coeff[1] := 1;
    for k := 2 to N do begin
      Coeff[k] := 1;
      for i := k - 2 downto 0 do
        Coeff[i + 1] := Coeff[i] - A[k-1] * Coeff[i + 1];
      Coeff[0] := -A[k-1] * Coeff[0];
    end;

    Result := Coeff[N - M];
    if Odd(N - M) then
      Result := - Result;
  end;
```

calls CalcMultiComb([1, 2, 3, 4], M) with M=1..4 give results 10, 35, 50, 24

Comment: Interestingly this can be improved to O(n log n) using fast polynomial interpolation with FFT.

Answer (score 4):

I have a Dynamic programming solution in my mind, just want to share. Time complexity is O(k*n^2) with n is total number.

The idea is, we start to fill in each position from 0 to k -1. So if we assume at position `ith`, the number to be filled for this position is `a`, so the sum of all combination start with `a` will be `a` times the total of all combination from position `(i + 1)th` starting with `(a + 1)`

Note: I have updated the solution, so it can work with any array `data`, My language is Java, so you can notice that the index for array is 0 based, which start from 0 to n-1.

```
public int cal(int n, int k , int[]data){
   int [][] dp = new int[k][n + 1];
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
       dp[k - 1][i] = data[i - 1];
   }
   for(int i = k - 2; i >= 0; i--){
       for(int j = 1 ; j <= n; j++){
           for(int m = j + 1 ; m <= n; m++){
               dp[i][j] += data[j - 1]*dp[i + 1][m];
           }
       }
   }
   int total = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
       total += dp[0][i];
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, the naive approach is O((n!)/(k!)(n-k)!) and this is polynomial  O(k*n^2)

Comment: sorry; I misread the exponent as being exponential in some parameter.

Comment: Is this solution only for an array with elements in arithmetic progression with difference = 1 and first element as 1?

Comment: Why O(k * n^2)? It's simple to implement this in O(k * n), with the state `f(i, j)` = sum of products of all size-j subsets of the first i elements. Then we have `f(i, j) = f(i-1, j-1) * a[i] + f(i-1, j)`, an O(1) transition.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, correct :) will find sometimes to modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the same problem. I found the solution via Vieta's Algorithm as well. I tweaked the algorithm not the calculate the coefficient of the polynomial which are not needed. The complexity is O(N*M). I looked into DFTs and FFTs but if M is small enough, this method will be even faster than Fast Fourier Transformation algorithms. This is java btw.

```
public BigInteger sumOfCombMult(Integer[] roots, int M)
{
    if (roots.length < M)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("size of roots cannot be smaller than M");
    }

    BigInteger[] R = new BigInteger[roots.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
    {
        R[i] = BigInteger.valueOf(roots[i]);
    }

    BigInteger[] coeffs = new BigInteger[roots.length + 1];

    coeffs[0] = BigInteger.valueOf(roots[0]);

    int lb = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < roots.length; i++)
    {
        lb = Math.max(i - M, 0);

        coeffs[i] = R[i].add(coeffs[i - 1]);

        for (int j = i - 1; j > lb; j--)
        {
            coeffs[j] = R[i].multiply(coeffs[j]).add(coeffs[j - 1]);

        }

        if (lb == 0)
        {
            coeffs[0] = coeffs[0].multiply(R[i]);
        }
    }

    return coeffs[roots.length - M];
}
```