# How to find coefficient of x^m in the polynomial?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, polynomial-math

How to find coefficient of

```
x^m (m<=n)
```

in the polynomial of type

```
(a1+b1x)(a2+b2x)...(an+bnx)? O(n^2)
```

Algorithm needed!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure math, not a programming issue.

Comment: Pure math approach is not always appropriate for this problem because n! complexity is unreal for considerable size input, so optimal algorithm is needed

Comment: Well the question is all about the dynamic programming solution for calculating the required answer in feasible time complexity.Every coefficient cannot be calculated using pen and paper. Therefore, there must be some way to make the process automated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(a1+b1x)(a2+b2x)...(an+bnx)=b1*b2*...*bn*(a1/b1+x)*(a2/b2+x)...(a/bn+x)
```

Right part is polynomial with roots (-a1/b1,-a2/b2...-an/bn)

There is O(N^2) algorithm to find coefficients of this polynomial, implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23537841/844416)

(Don't forget to multiply coefficients by product of b[i])

Answer (score 0):

Speaking personally I would use an inductive application of the Binomial Theorem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

This will solve your base case of two binomials. Then the rest is just repeating the application using the associativity of multiplication.

I don't know enough C to write this though, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Coefficient of `m`-th element is sum of all possible products of `(a or b)[i]` for all `i` between `0` and `m` such that there are exactly `m` selections of `b` (and `n - m` selections of `a`).

More procedurally, [generate](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C) all [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of integers between `0` and `m`, multiply elements of `a` at those indices, get a [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of each combination and multiply the obtained product further by the elements of `b` at those indices. Add all obtained products together.