# Calculating sums of pairwise products, triple-wise products and so on

Tags: python, algorithm

1) Problem formulation:

Given a vector of length n: `a=[a1,a2,..,an]`, I need to calculate vector `b=[b1,b2,..bn]`, such that:

```
b1=a1+a2+...+an
b2=a1a2+a1a3+...+a1an+a2a3+...+a2an+...+a{n-1}an
b3=a1a2a3+a1a2a4+...+a1a2an+a1a3a4+...
...
bn=a1a2a3...an
```

Each successive entry of `b` contains the sum of entries of `a`, sum of pairwise products, triple-wise products and so on.

Does anyone know efficient algorithm or may be an existing library where this is implemented?

I was thinking something like

```
b1=sum(a)
b2=a1*sum(a[1,:])+a2*sum(a[2,:])+...
```

And similarly for all other entries.

2) Why I need this:

I want to perform 1D function integration using Lagrange interpolation polynomial expansion. My problem is an extension of Newton-Cotes formula. This formula is used to calculate definite integrals. Unlike Newton-Cotes, I would like to calculate the full antiderivate of a given function f at chosen collocation points, thus I have to integrate each Lagrange interpolation polynomial.

I don't need working code. I am more interested in algorithm and whether this has been already implemented.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Edit: Example:

Let `a=[1,2,3,4]`.

Then

`b=[1+2+3+4,1*2+1*3+1*4+2*3+2*4+3*4,1*2*3+1*2*4+1*3*4+2*3*4,1*2*3*4]=[10,35,50,24]`

Comment: @pault, that was obviously a typo. I've added an example

Comment: The example really helped- I was about to post the same solution as @blhsing did below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import combinations
from operator import mul
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print([sum(reduce(mul, c) for c in combinations(a, i + 1)) for i in range(len(a))])
```

This outputs:

```
[10, 35, 50, 24]
```

Comment: @pault, as far as I remember, it is recommended to wait 1-2 days before accepting any answer: first, the provided answer can (in theory)  be wrong and second, more elegant/fast solution can appear. Even though I doubt that this is the case here, I generally prefer to wait before accepting any answer

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of completeness, I would like to suggest my own alternative solution using recursion. It is easy to note, that if for some `a=[a1,a2,...,an]` we know `b=[b1,b2,...bn]`, than for a vector `a'=[a1,a2,...,an,a{n+1}]` (such that the first `n` terms coincide with vector `a`) the solution will be:

```
b'=[b1+a{n+1},b2+b1*a{n+1},b3+b2*a{n+1},...,b{n}+b{n-1}*a{n+1},b{n}*a{n+1}]
```

Therefore, a solution based on recursion is simply:

```
def f2(a):
if len(a)==1:
    return a
else:
    return np.append(f2(a[:-1])+np.append([1],f2(a[:-1])[:-1])*a[-1],[a[-1]*f2(a[:-1])[-1]])
```

The result is identical with the solution above, however benchmarking shows that the solution suggested by @blhsing is more efficient.